# id() on captured accumulator

Tags: saxon, xslt-3.0

I have an accumulator that holds certain xs:ID typed data. I want to reference it using the id() function, and initially I thought this worked. It does, but only when the `accumulator-after('acc')/id function is supplied a string literal. If an expression is passed (e.g. a node), the function will return nothing. I tested the global id() function (with streaming turned off) and it works as expected. Here is my test case

XSD

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    targetNamespace="urn:test" xmlns:ns1="urn:test">
    <xsd:complexType name="IDHolder" abstract="false" mixed="true">
        <xsd:attribute name="ObjectId" type="xsd:ID" use="required"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="RootElement">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:element name="MiddleElement">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xsd:element name="ChildElement" type="ns1:IDHolder"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>
                    </xsd:complexType>
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="ObjectId" type="xsd:IDREF" use="required"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

XSL

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math" xmlns:t="urn:test"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math" version="3.0" expand-text="yes">
    <xsl:mode streamable="yes" use-accumulators="#all"/>
    <xsl:import-schema schema-location="issuereporo.xsd" namespace="urn:test"/>
    <xsl:accumulator name="acc" as="node()?" initial-value="()" streamable="yes">
        <xsl:accumulator-rule xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/" match="t:MiddleElement" select="."
            phase="end" saxon:capture="yes"/>
    </xsl:accumulator>
    <xsl:template match="t:RootElement">
        <xsl:apply-templates />        
        <xsl:variable name="vAcc" select="accumulator-after('acc')"/> 
        Direct Access 
        {$vAcc/id('_1')}
        Access via context node
<!--THIS IS WHAT DOESN'T WORK-->
        {$vAcc/id(@ObjectId)} 
        Access via global
        <!-- will only work when streaming is off --> 
        {id(@ObjectId)} 
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RootElement xmlns="urn:test" ObjectId="_2"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="urn:test file:/C:/Users/john/Documents/GitHub/streamatron-test/issuereporo.xsd">
    <MiddleElement>
        <ChildElement ObjectId="_1">C
        </ChildElement>
        <ChildElement ObjectId="_2">D
        </ChildElement>        
    </MiddleElement>
</RootElement>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `{$vAcc/id(current()/@ObjectId)}` instead of `{$vAcc/id(@ObjectId)}`.